# Does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_{n-1}}{n!}B_n(z)$ have closed form?

Tags: calculus, bernoulli-numbers, bernoulli-polynomials

I'm trying to evaluate the closed form of
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_{n-1}}{n!}B_n(z),$$ if there exists,
when the generating function of the Bernoulli Polynomials is:
$$\frac{t e^{xt}}{e^t-1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}B_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!},$$
and $B_n=B_n(0)$.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: The Bernoulli numbers act as $ (2n)! \, c^n$ with c<1, and the fraction $B_n(x)/n!$ is of order unity, so your series will diverge.  Are you aware you are working with a diverging series, and the pitfalls of assigning meaning to it?  Did this series arise from an asymptotic analysis, say, of an integral?  If so, the integral is probably the best you'll get.